# getBoundingClientRect says undefined

Tags: javascript, properties

I am building a website which I want to have animation once the user scrolls down. I am having trouble with the getBoundingClientRect, as it says it is undefined in the console of the page. Thanks for your help!

```
var pointsArray = document.getElementsByClassName('point');

var animatePoints = function (points) {

    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        points[i].style.opacity = 1;
        points[i].style.transform = "scaleX(1) translateY(0)";
        points[i].style.msTransform = "scaleX(1) translateY(0)";
        points[i].style.WebkitTransform = "scaleX(1) translateY(0)";
    }
};

window.onload = function () {

    var sellingPoints = document.getElementsByClassName('selling-points')[0];
    var scrollDistance = sellingPoints.getBoundingClientRect().top - window.innerHeight + 200;

     window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {

         if (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop >= scrollDistance) {
             animatePoints(pointsArray);   
         }

    });
}
```

Comment: you probably want `var pointsArray = document.getElementsByClassName('point');` in window.onload as well, seeing as it will be empty if executed *too soon*

Comment: as to your problem, it seems you don't have an element with class containing `selling-points`

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, my selling-points class was different than I thought!